# Use multiple themes in react app on same time

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to change the overall theme of the React project. My app is in production, and I would like to change the theme one component at a time. After I have changed the theme, I would like to push that component into production. Is it possible to use multiple themes in a single React app at the same time?

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details about both your project's architecture as well as what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  In a general sense, yes, because each component can import its own stylesheet and if you're specific with your class names, you can keep certain sections of your site's theme separate from each other, but you've given us no information about your specific project to weigh in on.

Comment: Are you using ChakraUI, Bootstrap, MaterialUI, custom CSS, Tailwind?

Comment: @Zachiah My current theam is in Bootsrap and new in is MaterialUI

Comment: So you want to use multiple style frameworks in the same app?

Comment: @Zachiah yes, want to use multiple style